# Is it possible to publish test results to a repo in Azure DevOps?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, test-results

I have a suite of unit tests that I would like to use as a source of documentation (to supplement our other documentation).

The unit tests are written in MSTest and we use the "Visual Studio Test Task" within our Azure DevOps builds to ensure they all pass.

We are currently in the process of putting together documentation for each of our repos (stored in GIT in Azure DevOps) but I am reluctant to manually write documentation that explains scenarios that we already have covered in unit tests.

I have found the area of Azure DevOps that lists all the test runs across all the builds/repos but this isn't what I am after.

What I would like to do, is to be able to reference the latest test results for a given repo from within the repo (maybe a link in the readme.md file).

Is there some way that I can maybe publish the latest test results to a static location?

Comment: I have come across the post below that describes using SpecFlow and Pickle which looks similar to what I require although I thought there may be something that hooks directly in to MSTest?

http://blog.majcica.com/2018/05/07/living-documentation-and-test-reports-in-vsts-tfs-pipelines/

Comment: For your requirements,I am afraid this is not feasible.You can refer to this case(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/359308/can-i-get-test-cases-outcome-results-as-a-field-in.html) to see if it could help you.